# How to stack matrices with different size

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch, stack, resize

I have a list of matrices with size of `(63,32,1,600,600)`, when I want to stack it with `torch.stack(matrices).cpu().detach().numpy()` it's raising with error:

"stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [32, 1, 600, 600] at entry 0 and [16, 1, 600, 600] at entry 62". Is tried for resizing but it did not work. I appreciate any recommendations.

Comment: Have you tried setting which dimension the matrices are stacked on to.

Comment: Yes, I tried  torch.stack(matrices, dim=0).cpu().detach().numpy() and raised with same error.

Comment: Are you sure all the tensors are the same size. Could you send an example list.

Comment: `(63,32,1,600,600)` is that the shape of the tensor you are looking to get from the list of `(*, 1, 600, 600)` tensors?

Comment: @Dwight, yes I am sure since this is output of my cnn network with 32 batches and images with size 600x600 pixels. I am not sure how to generate an example out of my main code.

Comment: @Ivan, Yes that's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do is stack the outputted mini-batches together into a single batch. My bet is that your last batch is partially filled (only has *16* elements instead of *32*).

Instead of using [`torch.stack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.stack.html) (creating a new axis), I would simply concatenate with [`torch.cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html) on the batch axis (`axis=0`). Assuming `matrices` is a *list* of `torch.Tensor`s.

```
torch.cat(matrices).cpu().detach().numpy()
```

As `torch.cat` concatenates on `axis=0` by default.

Answer (score 0):

When we have tensors that differ in size only on the first dimension, [as of PyTorch v1.7.0](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v1.7.0), we can use [`torch.vstack()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.vstack.html) to stack it along axis 0. Using `torch.stack()` fails here because it expects all the tensors to be of same shape.

Here is a reproducible illustration matching your problem description:

```
# sample tensors (as per your size)
In [65]: t1 = torch.randn([32, 1, 600, 600])
In [66]: t2 = torch.randn([16, 1, 600, 600])

# vertical stacking (i.e., stacking along axis 0)
In [67]: stacked = torch.vstack([t1, t2])

# check shape of output
In [68]: stacked.shape
Out[68]: torch.Size([48, 1, 600, 600])
```

we get `48 (32 + 16)` as the size of first dimension in the result because we're stacking tensors along that dimension.

---

Note:

You can also initialize the result tensor, say `stacked`, by explicitly calculating the shape and pass this tensor as a parameter to `out=` kwarg of `torch.vstack()` if you want to write the result to a specific tensor, for instance updating the values of existing tensor (of same shape). However, this is optional.

```
# calculate new shape of stacking
In [80]: newshape = (t1.shape[0] + t2.shape[0], *t1.shape[1:])

# allocate an empty tensor, filled with garbage values
In [81]: stacked = torch.empty(newshape)

# stack it along axis 0 and write the result to `stacked`
In [83]: torch.vstack([t1, t2], out=stacked)

# check shape/size
In [84]: stacked.shape
Out[84]: torch.Size([48, 1, 600, 600])
```

Comment: I am wondering why it raised with error : "module 'torch' has no attribute 'vstack'"

Comment: @Aras thanks for pointing it out. I've updated the answer to mention that the API has been added only in PyTorch 1.7.0. Having access to these sort of APIs is one of the benefits of using latest builds but I agree that it's not always possible :)